# Nonlinear optimization using parallel input/output

Tags: computer-science, nonlinear-optimization, computational-mathematics

I have a system that accepts a vector and returns a function value. The goal is to change the elements of the vector such that the function value is minimized using a derivative-free solver, eg. using NOMAD. The structure of the problem allows to pass `n` vectors to the function at once and receive `n` function values in return within about the same computation time.

The solvers, which I have found so far, will only pass 1 vector to the function at a time and wait for the function value to be returned.

Is there a solver, which allows "parallel processing" on a single-cpu? Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think this question is more suitable to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ than here. Maybe you can get quick responses at scicomp than from here.

Comment: But many people ask about optimization on math.stackexchange, and optimization is an important topic in applied math, so I think math.stackexchange is also an ok place for this question.